# Open sets using union and intersection of sets in R2

Tags: general-topology

Let *U* and *V* be open sets in $\mathbb R^2$ a) show that *U* $\cap$ *V* is open. b) show that *U* $\cup$ *V* is open

Comment: Metric space definitions? That should be pointed out. By topology definitions an intersection/union of open sets are open.  By definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the metric topology definition of openness:

Let $x \in U \cap V$. Then $X \in U$ and so by openness of $U$ there is some $r_1 >0$ such that $B(x,r_1) \subseteq U$. Likewise $x \in V$ and we have $r_2>0$ with $B(x,r_2) \subseteq V$. Then $r=\min(r_1,r_2)$ obeys $B(x,r) \subseteq U \cap V$. So $U \cap V$ is open.

If $x \in U \cup V$, then $x\in U$ or $x \in V$. WLOG, $x \in U$, and we have $r>0$ with $B(x,r) \subseteq U \subseteq U \cup V$. So $U \cup V$ is open (in fact any union will do, for the minimum argument we can only do finitely many open sets in the intersection).

Answer (score 1):

a) We have to prove that for all $x\in U\cap V$ there exist a $\delta >0$ such that $B(x,\delta)= \{y \in \mathbb{R}^{2}:\|x-y\|<\delta \} \subset U \cap V$

Let $x \in U \cap V$ then $x\in U$ and $x\in V$

As $U$ is a open set, we have that there exist $\delta_{1} > 0 $ such that $B(x,\delta_{1}) \subset U$ and as $V$ is a open set, we have that there exist $\delta_{2}>0$ such that $B(x,\delta_{2}) \subset V$

Then, if we take $\delta = min\{\delta_{1}, \delta_{2} \}$ we have that $B(x,\delta) \subset B(x,\delta_{1}) \subset U$ and $B(x,\delta) \subset B(x,\delta_{2}) \subset V$ then $B(x, \delta) \subset U \cap V$ and we are done!

b)For the union of sets is easier, because, let $x \in U \cup V$ then $x \in U$ or $x \in V$

As both of them are opens set, if $x \in U$ then there exist $\delta_{1}>0$ such that $B(x,\delta_{1}) \subset U \subset U \cup V$
The same if $x \in V$

And we are done!

I hope this help you